# Coderush and Productivity Power Tools overlapped functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2010, coderush

I just started using Coderush and found some stuff that I used to have already with Power Tools extension installed. So I disabled some PowerTools options, now the picture looks like this:

[image]

I think there is something else left that I should have disabled as well, because Coderush provides better functionality?

Can't get rid of PowerTools entirely. I really love the solution navigator though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up turning off Automatic Brace Completion (CR does this better I think) and Ctrl+Click Go To Definition (I use CR "Marker before Jump" and F12) as well.

I really like the Solution Navigator too, but it can get laggy if you've got a bunch of things expanded in a larger solution (or so it seems to me currently).